# .htaccess specific problem with formation

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

If format is `Dir-$mrpagename-$mrid.htm` then .htaccess is

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule Dir-(.*)-(.*)\.htm$ index.php?page=browse&category=$2
```

for `http://sitename/Dir-dirbrowse-3.htm`

But if format is `$mrpagename-$mrid` then what will be .htaccess for `http://sitename/dirbrowse-3`?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)-(\d+)$ /index.php?page=browse&category=$2 [NC,L]
```

Based on your example `dirbrowse-3` (`$mrpagename-$mrid`) I put these "restrictions" to properly match URLs (you will need to modify this rule if these parts can have any other characters):

- `$mrpagename` part can be letters or digits
- `$mrid` part can only be digits

I did it (restrictions) because your original rule (the `(.*)` part) is quite broad and can catch other forms of URLs as well which may lead to `category` parameter having invalid data.